# how to prevent preg_match/preg_match_all from creating unnecessary array elements

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, php-7, regex-group

I am learning Regular expressions and testing it with php and an online tool. When i run following php code, it creates an array with 2 elements which is correct and even make sense:-

```
preg_match('/(ab)+/', "ababab ab ab", $match); // captured group
print_r($match);
```

It returns:-

```
Array
(
  [0] => ababab  // matched word
  [1] => ab      // one captured group.
)
```

I've tested it here and it shows the same output(i.e., one match and one captured group):-
https://regex101.com/r/5OYlY2/3

**But** When i change regular expression and convert it into a named group then preg_match returns 3 elements. I don't know why it is returning 3 elements because the same expression is giving only 2 output ( one match and one **named group**) here:-
https://regex101.com/r/NdS6K7/3

**code**:-

```
// with named group
preg_match('/(?P<demo>ab)+/', "ababab ab ab", $match); 
print_r($match); // returning array of 3 elements which it should not
```

**Unexpected output**:-

```
Array
(
  [0] => ababab // one match, fine.
  [demo] => ab // a named group, makes sense
  [1] => ab // why on the earth this element was created?
)
```

**why** preg_match is returning 3 elements in case of named group regular expression? Why not it creates only 2 elements like this:-

**Expected output**:-

```
Array
(
  [0] => ababab // one match, fine.
  [demo] => ab // a named group, makes sense
)
```

**Edit**
I want everything in the array except indexed elements, i.e., i want not only named elements but also matched elements.

Comment: @mickmackusa  I want both matched elements and named group elements. For example, i have a sentence in which i am checking for occurrence of all vowels.:-

    $str = "The first regex has a named group (TAG), while the second one";

using this code:-

    preg_match_all('/(?P<lower>[aeiou])|(?P<upper>[AEIOU])/', $str, $vowelcase);

It returns array of 5 elements, but i want only 3 , one - set of all matched elements, two - set of lower case vowel elements, three - set of upper case vowel elements.

Comment: This will fix your output array: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/270d1198be4cd29750a4bdd1d8258bf1781fa747

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thanks